# Water levels during global warming

Tags: trigonometry

Water levels near a glacier currently average 9 feet, varying seasonally by 2 inches above and below the average and reaching their highest point in January. Due to global warming, the glacier has begun melting faster than normal. Every year, the water levels rise by a steady 3 inches. Find a function modeling the depth of the water t months from now. 
I don't know how they come up with this model:
D(t) = 2cos(π/6 * t) +108 + 1/4*t

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.  I'm not certain whether the last term is supposed to be ${t\over4}$ or ${1\over4t}$

Comment: Seasonal variation, baseline of $9 \times 12$ inches, and trend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In inches, the average level is $108$. We need to add a period-$12$ mean-$0$ term to this to get what would happen without global warming. This gives $108+A\cos\frac{\pi t}{6}$ for some $A$, provided we choose $t=0$ to denote a seasonal peak. The amplitude $A$ has to be $2$, so the seasonal variation is $2$ inches above or below the average. Finally, each month sees a quarter-inch trendline rise from global warming, giving the stated $D(t)$.

Comment: However, the model doesn't take into account the total volume of ice that can melt, hence the maximum growth of water level. The growth is obviously not $t/4$ until the end of times.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The other problem with the model is period-$12$, mean-$0$, peaking at $0$ doesn't imply proportionality to $\cos\frac{\pi t}{6}$, because e.g. the function could be proportional to $\cos\frac{\pi t}{6}+k\cos\frac{\pi t}{3}$ for some $k\ne 0$. It's only a "lowest-order" model.